# df reports strange inode info

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

On my external hard disk I did a

```
df /Volumes/HD_INTENSO
```

and got

```
Filesystem   512-blocks      Used  Available Capacity iused ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk3s1 1953038208 425524480 1527513728    22%       0     0  100%   /Volumes/HD_INTENSO
```

The zero free inodes look ridiculous to me, not only because I have just before emptied my recycle bin (which freed about 200000 files), but also because I can create new files - so there should be free inodes.

The file happens to be formatted unfortunately as *FAT32*, and I could imagine that this places restrictions on the inodes, but even in this case, this should not show me that no inodes are left, and at the same time allow me to create new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAT32 doesn't have inodes, it has a File Allocation Table; therefore used & free inodes are zero - but also 100% of the possible total.

See [SuperUser - What is the difference between FAT and Inode?](https://superuser.com/questions/1218337/what-is-the-difference-between-fat-and-inode)
Also, linked from there - Wikipedia
[File Allocation Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) &
[Inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)